# How not to skip the first element with .data()

Tags: d3.js

The **data** array contains exactly 5 objects.

The following code displays only the last 4,  and skip the first :

```
d3.csv(csv_data, function(error, data){

  var table = d3.select("#div");

  var tr = table.selectAll("tr")
     .data(data)
     .enter()
     .append("tr");

  var td =  tr.selectAll("td")
     .data(function(d){return [d.x,d.y];})
     .enter()
     .append("td")
     .html(function(d){return d;});

});
```

Comment: The code seems fine...[fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/t54XS/1/).

Comment: You already have a `tr` element in your `#div`.

Comment: Good one ! I'm glad to know it now. Thank @Lars